# How to overide the CSS of Django UserCreationForm and AuthenticationForm without losing in built functionality?

Tags: css, django, django-forms

I'm using the `AuthenticationForm` class to log users in, and the `UserCreationForm` to allow users to create accounts. Everything worked when I was just rendering the default form (using `{{ form.as_p }}` in my HTML files. However, I wanted to make the forms look nicer so I've over ridden the forms as so:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=TextInput(attrs={
                                        'class': "block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4",
                                        "name": "username", "placeholder": "Username"}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={
                                        'class': "block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4",
                                        "name": "password", "placeholder": "Password"}))
```

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=EmailInput(attrs={
                                        'class': "block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4",
                                        "name": "email", "placeholder": "Email"}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={
                                        'class': "block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4",
                                        "name": "password1", "placeholder": "Password"}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={
                                        'class': "block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4",
                                        "name": "password2", "placeholder": "Confirm password"}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
        widgets = {
            'username': TextInput(attrs={'class': "block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4",
                                         "type": "text", "name": "username", "placeholder": "Username"}),
            'first_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': "block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4",
                                           "type": "text", "name": "first_name", "placeholder": "First Name"}),
            'last_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': "block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4",
                                          "type": "text", "name": "last_name", "placeholder": "Last Name"}),
        }
```

However, in doing so I appear to have lost some of the out-of-the-box functionality these forms provide, such as the `UserCreationForm` checking `password1` and `password2` are the same, and providing a message back to the user.

Have I done something wrong? Ultimately all I want to do is keep all the functionality that comes with these forms but just add the tailwind class `"block border border-grey-light w-full p-3 rounded mb-4"` to them.

`views.py` login function:

```
def login_user(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/first')
            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "registration/login.html", context)
```

Comment: Ultimatly CSS can't change html functionality so somewhere you changed something else.

Comment: I'm not overriding the built in functionality when I initialise the ```username``` and ```password``` widgets like so ```password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(```?

Comment: It looks to be the fact that I've referenced each object in my ```login.html``` file like this: ```{{ form.username }}``` and ```{{ form.password }}```. When I change this to ```{{ form.as_p }}``` the functionality comes back. The problem is the formatting isn't quite the same so I find it easier to work with each individual object, vs rendering the form in one go. For example, when I do it with ```{{ form.as_p }}``` I can't get rid of the labels